# How use $PropertyType for function stateless components of react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I need get the type of function component for use it with $PropertyType utility. How can i do that work for me with due error?

```js
// This code not work with component as function

function Button({loading, children}: {|
    loading: boolean,
    children: string,
|}) {
    return (
        <button>
            {children}
            {loading && <div className="loading"/>}
        </button>
    )
};

function SpecialButton({loading}: {|
    loading: $PropertyType<$PropertyType<typeof Button, 'props'>, 'loading'>
|}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button loading={loading}>
                special text
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}

const specButton = <SpecialButton loading={10000}/> // <-- no error
// (its NOT OK for me)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you declare a type `ButtonProps` and use `$PropertyType` on that?

```
import React from 'react';

type ButtonProps = {| loading: boolean, children: string |};
type SpecialButtonProps = {| loading: $PropertyType<ButtonProps, 'loading'> |};

function Button({ loading, children }: ButtonProps) {
    return (
        <button>
            {children}
            {loading && <div className="loading"/>}
        </button>
    )
};

function SpecialButton({ loading }: SpecialButtonProps) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button loading={loading}>
                special text
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}

const specButton = <SpecialButton loading={10000} /> // Error!
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgCEBXGGCAOwAUcwBnOALxwA3gB84AGwgoAJsHYBzAFxwARhAgTU7ADRw0AC2ASZRdit4wo8hXFEBfCjTpwAynTTAUE5qw7cIPkERcSlZGxUAEgC6WGoAFVokAB5fNi4eXj18MLlFfAA+O0dKTCZ2DGAORhZ0gAphSWk8hT1DY1Mkdjh7FTT-TIBKEXI4MbgiGCYobrrR8YXk1VqOAvmFjZF2kzN7dc3x4VybOAAyU7hkuQA3fQkUXl4AORQQJAEAImPFD4B6Ar2B0uv2WfnYawWg3IJXIZQqMCq3XcSE83n67AaTXCih6KmRqJ8KwygV4w2E+0m01m+0WNwhQPGqSJWJaAiOzRs9npDI2vA8XgkcBgSAAHjAaQdkr90dyNlK6fsoXtyGgOJY4HyUejgsl8QLtd8FGyAIwABnNpvscH+1t+cAAolAcFAAIRAA)

Also, check out [How to validate optional fields with `$Diff`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304385/how-to-validate-optional-fields-with-diff) for more tips on how to type React component props.