# How to validate optional fields with `$Diff`?

Tags: flowtype

I want my type to validate "default props" passed to the React component but `$Diff` (which is designed for this) is not doing so. How can I get this behavior?

```js
/* @flow */

type Props = { name: string, age: number };
type DefaultProps = { age: number };
type RequiredProps = $Diff<Props, DefaultProps>;

const a1: RequiredProps = { name: 'foo' };
const a2: RequiredProps = { name: 'foo', age: 1 };
const a3: RequiredProps = { name: 'foo', age: '1' }; // why no error?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Diff<A, B>` returns an object type that, by default, will accept additional properties. This means, that any properties that are on `A` and `B` can be on an object of type `$Diff<A, B>` with any type. In your case, `RequiredProps` is equivalent to `{ name: string }`. Thus, an object `{ name: '', age: <whatever> }: RequiredProps` is completely valid for any value of `<whatever>`.

It seems like what you really want is an object type that requires all of the properties of `RequiredProps` **and** requires that any property from `DefaultProps` matches that type definition. This can be achieved with the type,

```
type RequiredAndDefaultProps = { ...$Exact<RequiredProps>, ...DefaultProps };
```

which can be verified

```
type Props = { name: string, age: number };
type DefaultProps = { age: number };
type RequiredProps = $Diff<Props, DefaultProps>;
type RequiredAndDefaultProps = { ...$Exact<RequiredProps>, ...DefaultProps };

({ name: 'foo' }: RequiredAndDefaultProps);
({ name: 'foo', age: 42 }: RequiredAndDefaultProps);
({ name: 'foo', age: '42' }: RequiredAndDefaultProps); // Error: age should be number
({ age: 42 }: RequiredAndDefaultProps); // Error: missing name
({ name: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }: RequiredAndDefaultProps);
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbygOwIYC2EAXFMsHAJY4DmANFHjSbgK4EBGEcUAvgNwAoUJCgARCADM8rADbB4SVBmxMWOdlx4Dh4aACUIAR1aU4EACaKU6KABIxlSZIA815AwnS5CxCgB8QiIGxqbmFgCCOBZeMvLuttgAdCl2AKIAHngAxsAuhiZmlu7+DClJsT4JOoIAFNj4RKQA5JIICM18pAVhllExUnG+SgCUQvW4hCyt7c0MaqQALABMXVA9RZHRlfF+yGN1DVMtbR3zzC0rnbzdoZv9O8MoY1AA9K9QaXCIcKRqZAALBByCxQLhsTjcQ6MC5QFZrDbhB6DKp7F7vT7fBC-KAESjIZDUGiTIjQxrTU5zMF4HHNDg0663QpI7Yo3ajfhAA).